# How usage function in sql server multiple

Tags: sql-server

I have a problem in database

SINGLE USER NAME: my_user
ACCESS database: database1, database2, database3

SELECT
 NAME,
dbo.myfunction() as test // this comand not ready, i try database1..dbo.myfunction not work, try database1.dbo.myfunction not work
FROM
 database1..table, database2..table2

how to run a function?
regards.
marco

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that you have created function successfully. You can test it.

```
select  dbo.myfunction() as test
```

see full details related to functions in sql here.

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms186755.aspx

If you can test your function simply you should be able to call your function anywhere you want to use as a column.

If you still fails to run it. Provide code how you created your function. cheers.
Fahad